# How to make Array<String> Hashable?

Tags: swift, protocols, swift3, hashable

I'm trying to make `Array<String>` conform to `Hashable`, in Swift 3 preview 6:

```
extension Array: Hashable where Element: Hashable {
    public var hashValue: Int {
        var hashValue = 0
        for element in self {
            hashValue ^= element.hashValue
        }
        return hashValue
    }
}

var data = Dictionary<Array<String>, Any>()
```

But I get the following error and have no idea why:

```
ERROR at line 4, col 1: extension of type 'Array' with constraints cannot have an inheritance clause
extension Array: Hashable where Element: Hashable {
^
```

How can I make the array hashable?